# perl quoting in ftp->ls with wildcard

Tags: perl, ftp, wildcard, quotes, ls

contents of remote directory  `mydir` :

```
blah.myname.1.txt
blah.myname.somethingelse.txt
blah.myname.randomcharacters.txt
blah.notmyname.1.txt
blah.notmyname.2.txt
...
```

in perl, I want to download all of this stuff with `myname`

I am failing *really* hard with the appropriate quoting.  please help.

failed code

```
my @files;
@files = $ftp->ls( '*.myname.*.txt' );  # finds nothing
@files = $ftp->ls( '.*.myname.*.txt' );  # finds nothing
```

etc..

How do I put the wildcards so that they are interpreted by the `ls`, but not by perl?  What is going wrong here?

Comment: are you sure perl's ls function accepts wildcards? ftp clients do the file filtering themselves, not the remote system, so the wildcards may never get out there. you might have to retrieve the full dir listing yourself and do your own matching.

Comment: @MarcB what do you mean - "the ftp clients do the file filtering themselves"?  Do they not handle wildcards??

Comment: they do, but have you checked that perl's ftp lib does?. e.g. `$ftp->ls('*')`? if it did wildcards, that would just return everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume that you are using the [`Net::FTP`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egbarr/libnet-1.22/Net/FTP.pm) package. Then this part of the docs is interesting:

> #### `ls ( [ DIR ] )`
>
> Get a directory listing of DIR, or the current directory.
>
> In an array context, returns a list of lines returned from the server. In a scalar context, returns a reference to a list.

This means that if you call this method with no arguments, you get a *list of **all** files* from the current directory, else from the directory specified.

There is no word about any patterns, which is not suprising: FTP is just a protocol to transfer files, and this module only a wrapper around that protocoll.

You can do the filtering easily with `grep`:

```
my @interesting = grep /pattern/, $ftp->ls();
```

To select all files that contain the character sequence `myname`, use `grep /myname/, LIST`.
To select all files that contain the character sequence `.myname.`, use `grep /\.myname\./, LIST`.
To select all files that end with the character sequence `.txt`, use `grep /\.txt$/, LIST`.

The `LIST` is either the `$ftp->ls` or another grep, so you can easily chain multiple filtering steps.

Of course, Perl Regexes are more powerful than that, and we could do all the filtering in a single `/\.myname\.[^.]+\.txt$/` or something, depending on your *exact* requirements. If you are desperate for a globbing syntax, there are tools available to convert glob patterns to regex objects, like [`Text::Glob`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erclamp/Text-Glob-0.09/lib/Text/Glob.pm), or even to do direct glob matching:

```
use Text::Glob qw(match_glob);

my @interesting = match_glob ".*.myname.*.txt", $ftp->ls;
```

However, that is inelegant, to say the least, as regexes are *far* more powerful and *absolutely* worth learning.

Comment: Thank you.  My primary problem was that I was trying to get the wildcards to be interpreted "during" the `ls`.